# Creating NumPy matrix of a given size in a vectorized manner

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

If there a built-in NumPy function or any *vectorized* approach to generate the following 2D NumPy matrices for value of `n` > 1? Let me give some examples for the ***desired matrices*** for `n` equal to 2, 3, and 4.

One approach would be to construct a matrix of 1’s in the lower triangular part and then simply multiply by a vector `np.arange(1, n+1)`. Any other alternatives?

```
import numpy as np
```

***For n = 2***

```
n = 2
arr = np.array([[1, 0], [2, 2]])

# array([[1, 0],
#        [2, 2]])
```

***For n = 3***

```
n = 3
arr = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [2, 2, 0], [3, 3, 3]])

# array([[1, 0, 0],
#        [2, 2, 0],
#        [3, 3, 3]])
```

***For n = 4***

```
n = 4
arr = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 0, 0], [3, 3, 3, 0], [4, 4, 4, 4]])

# array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
#        [2, 2, 0, 0],
#        [3, 3, 3, 0],
#        [4, 4, 4, 4]])
```

---

**My attempt** (example for `n = 4`) using nested `for` loops. It works for any value of `n` > 1:

```
import numpy as np

n = 4
arr = np.zeros((n, n))

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        arr[i][j] = i+1 

# array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [2., 2., 0., 0.],
#        [3., 3., 3., 0.],
#        [4., 4., 4., 4.]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use ranged array multiplied by the lower-triangular mask -

```
In [44]: n = 5

In [45]: np.arange(1,n+1)[:,None]*np.tri(n,dtype=bool)
Out[45]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 3, 0, 0],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 0],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]])
```

It's easily portable to `numexpr` to leverage multi-cores for large data given the arithmetic-oriented nature -

```
import numexpr as ne

ne.evaluate('A*B',{'A':np.arange(1,n+1)[:,None],'B':np.tri(n,dtype=bool)})
```

#### Benchmarking

Including all posted solutions here.

Benchmarking script -

```
import numpy as np
import perfplot

import numexpr as ne

def numexpr_range_broadcast(n):
    return ne.evaluate('A*B',{'A':np.arange(1,n+1)[:,None],'B':np.tri(n,dtype=bool)})

def where_method(n):
    x = np.arange(1,n+1)
    return np.where(x[:,None]>=x,x[:,None],0)

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: n,
    kernels=[
        lambda n: where_method(n),
        lambda n: np.tril(np.broadcast_to(np.arange(1, n+1)[:, None], (n, n))),
        lambda n: np.arange(1,n+1)[:,None]*np.tri(n,dtype=bool),
        lambda n: numexpr_range_broadcast(n),
        ],
    labels=['where','tril_broadacast','range_broadcast','numexpr_range_broadcast'],
    n_range=[10, 20, 50, 80, 100, 200, 500, 800, 1000, 2000, 5000],
    xlabel='n',
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    )
```

Output -

[image]

Hence, on lower `n's` little before `100`, `np.where` based one wins it and on larger `n's`, `numexpr` shines.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `np.tril` and `np.broadcast_to` to create the initial `arange` variant.

```
import numpy as np

n = 4
np.tril(np.broadcast_to(np.arange(1, n+1)[:, None], (n, n)))
```

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 3, 0],
       [4, 4, 4, 4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `np.where` and broadcasting:

```
x = np.arange(1,n+1)
np.where(x[:,None]>=x,x[:,None],0)
# array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
#        [2, 2, 0, 0],
#        [3, 3, 3, 0],
#        [4, 4, 4, 4]])
```